# Does writing data in odd offset in an array buffer that has that alignment result in UB?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[basic.align] p1 says:

> Object types have alignment requirements ([basic.fundamental], [basic.compound]) which place restrictions on the **addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated**.
>
> Attempting to create an object ([intro.object]) in storage that does not meet the alignment requirements of the object's type is **undefined behavior**.

Consider this example:

```cpp
int main(){
   alignas(double) unsigned char buff[10] = {0};
   char* ptr = buff;
   ptr++;
   *(double*)ptr = 1.0;  // #1
   double r = *(double*)ptr;  //#2
}
```

Does the write and read at `#1` and `#2` result in UB? `ptr++` make `ptr` points to the address that offsets `sizeof(char)` from the start, whether that address satisfies the alignment requirement of an object of type `double`?

Comment: What your example has to do with the quoted paragraph? You just violate strict aliasing.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The second step should be `new (p) double;`. However, we can argue that [intro.object] p13 says the operation create the object implicitly in the region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it causes undefined behavior. Like most UB, one of the possible results is that it'll appear to work. For example, on an x86 processor it'll generally work, but may (often will) have relatively poor performance.

You can check for the bad case pretty easily if you want to:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   alignas(double) unsigned char buff[10] = {0};
   unsigned char* ptr = buff;
   ptr++;
   if ((uintptr_t)ptr % alignof(double) != 0) {
       std::cout << "Trying some undefined behavior\n";
   }
    *(double*)ptr = 1.0;  // #1
    double r = *(double*)ptr;  //#2
}
```

I suppose there is a little room for question about the precise point of the result being undefined behavior.

For example, let's break your "#1" into two pieces:

```cpp
double *dptr = (double *)ptr;   // A
*dptr = 1.0;                    // B
```

So at A we're just converting the pointer to char to a pointer to double. When `ptr` doesn't meet the alignment requirements for `double` this line actually has behavior that's *unspecified* (rather than undefined). The compiler could, for example, silently round the address to a value that *is* aligned for the target type, in which case the following access could actually have defined behavior.

On the other hand, that's not required. The conversion could just yield a misaligned pointer, so at B when you attempt to dereference the pointer and write where it points, you then do get undefined behavior.

Comment: IIRC, undefined behavior is also caused by trying to use an object that has not been created (its lifetime has not started). One would need to use placement new first (or some of its wrappers). At least until C++20, which established _implicit object creation_ (which, I belive, applies in this case). Therefore, there is still UB in your code even with the correct alignment before C++20, right?

Comment: @DanielLangr: yes, there's that too, but in my view that's always been sort of a meaningless technicality. One of the most basic principles of C++ has always been that most C code is acceptable C++, but this meant that C code that, even indirectly, used (among other things) `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, wasn't acceptable C++ code at all. So while there were words to that effect there, nobody could ever take them seriously.

Comment: Some would say "language lawyer" makes that legitimate, but I'm forced to disagree. There are limits to what even a language lawyer can reasonably argue. If you drive full-speed through an area with reduced speed limit "when children are present" no sane real-life lawyer is going to try to defend you on the grounds that only one child was present, so technically that's not "children". At least in my view, similar limitations need to be placed on "language lawyer" as well.